# Failed to compile error when trying to use theme in my Vue project using iView

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, less, iview

I am trying to change the theme of iView in my Vue project. I followed the steps found in this link:

https://www.iviewui.com/docs/guide/theme-en

I created a folder called `my-theme` in my main project folder. Inside that, I have a file called `index.less`, which contains the styles for my theme. I also installed less-loader using the following command

```
npm install less-loader --save-dev
```

Then, I imported my theme in my `main.js` file like so:

```
import iView from 'iview';
import '../my-theme/index.less';

Vue.use(iView);
```

However, when I try to load my project, I get the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./my-theme/index.less (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--10-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--10-oneOf-3-2!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--10-oneOf-3-3!./my-theme/index.less)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'less'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/myapp/node_modules/less-loader/dist/index.js:8:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/myapp/node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

https://pastebin.com/wRSP65bX

How can I solve this issue? Thanks for any help.

**Update**

I also installed `less` using `npm install less --save`. Now I get this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./my-theme/index.less (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--10-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--10-oneOf-3-2!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--10-oneOf-3-3!./my-theme/index.less)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


// https://github.com/ant-design/ant-motion/issues/44
.bezierEasingMixin();
^
Inline JavaScript is not enabled. Is it set in your options?
      in /Users/myusername/myapp/node_modules/iview/src/styles/color/bezierEasing.less (line 110, column 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable javascript loaderOptions in vue.config.js

If you don't have **vue.config.js** file in the root folder of your project, let's create this file and paste the below code:

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            less: {
                javascriptEnabled: true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Otherwise, you just put this code to **vue.config.js** file. Your file now looks likes this:

```
module.exports = {
    ...// other options
    ...
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            less: {
                javascriptEnabled: true
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
};
```